# Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook Doesn't Close & Reopen Properly

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a very peculiar issue that only occurs on only one client's machine. The client will open an instance of an Excel workbook using the shortcut and it uses a custom Add-In to do work which works fine and then saves the file to the applicable drive. Then, when the client closes Excel, he uses the "X" button on the top right. Then, when opening a new instance of the workbook using the shortcut on the desktop, Excel opens immediately without the splash screen, without any Add In's at all, so this issue isn't just affecting my Add-In.

When this issue occurs after closing Excel, even though it is gone from the screen and taskbar, the Excel.exe process is still running in the background, which presumably is why it loads up a lot faster upon re-opening. However, it would appear that Excel has partially closed down as the Add-In's have been removed from memory.

I've noticed before that when the Excel.exe process is still "hanging around" in Task Manager that closing Windows Explorer causes the Excel.exe process to terminate.

I have absolutely no idea what's going on and am certain it has nothing to do with the custom Add-In.

Do you have any ideas on why this might be happening? I haven't even been able to reproduce this error by RDPing into the client's machine from my own.

Comment: How does the client open the Excel document? Double clicking in Windows Explorer? The fact you don't see it on the same machine is the interesting bit.  Try http://superuser.com/questions/459701

Comment: Yeah the first time the client opens the template file is via a shortcut on the Desktop. Then he'll make some edits and save it to a drive location using Save As. Then he'll close the template file he just altered using the red "X" in Excel and then try to open the file he just saved from the Windows Explorer. The issue seems to be that the Add-Ins are all being unloaded but the Excel process is not being killed. Then, since Excel is still running but has unloaded all Add-Ins, when he opens it, none of the Add-Ins are loaded.